# resetting keys changed by xmodmap

Tags: linux, xmodmap

I am playing around with `xmodmap filename` to assign among others, the Euro sign to the number five key on my US keyboard.

I have done some wrong assignments and want to reset them, and I don't want to restart X (ie logout).

How can I reset all keys? `xmodmap` doesn't seem to have a commandline option for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
setxkbmap -layout us
```

to get a clean start if things are wrong now. You can also save the state of a (still correct) mapping with `xmodmap -pke > filename` and use `filename` as input for everything to reset.

BTW:

```
keycode 108 = Mode_switch
keysym 5 = 5 percent EuroSign
```

should give you the € sign on <kbd>Right-Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>